# How to find the program name of an X window?

Tags: xorg, gnome-panel

I was just reading »[How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/q/58172/236)«. Some answers say that you should press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> to get the *Add to panel* dialogue. However my keyboard has no <kbd>Win</kbd>. So I was asking myself how to start the *Add to panel* window. Usually the best way is to enter the program name into a terminal. In this case I can't figure out the name.

I tested it on another computer and couldn't find the name in the process list. Also `xwininfo` or similar programs shoed no name. So what is the best way to figure out the name of the program which opened a (X) window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running `xprop _NET_WM_PID` from a terminal will put X into a special mode where you can click on a window to get that window's PID in the terminal.

Then run `ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe` and look at where the link is to to figure out what the program's file name is.

The following is a little python script take from a program I'm working on:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os, subprocess

# Function based on code from apport
def get_window_pid():
    xprop = subprocess.Popen(['xprop', '_NET_WM_PID'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (out, err) = xprop.communicate()
    if xprop.returncode == 0:
        try:
            return int(out.split()[-1])
        except ValueError:
            return -1
    else:
        return -1

def get_window_exe():
    pid = get_window_pid()
    
    if pid == -1:
        return ''
        
    return os.path.realpath('/proc/' + str(pid) + '/exe')

if __name__=='__main__':
    exe = get_window_exe()
    if exe == '':
        print 'Unable to identify window\'s executable' 
    else:
        print exe
```

Save this into a file and run by typing `python <filename>.py`. Click on the window and it will print the program's name.

Comment: Following your answer, I created a bash script with:
ls -l "/proc/$(xprop _NET_WM_PID | sed "s/^.*= //")/exe"

Answer (score 1):

Based on iBelieve's answer:

```
alias fxname='basename $(ll /proc/$(xprop _NET_WM_PID | awk "{print \$NF}")/exe | awk "{print \$NF}")'
```

The `$NF` in the awk commands must be escaped so it's not interpreted as a shell variable. As soon as you run it a reticle will appear for you to click on the desired window.

Comment: `ll` needs to be `ls -l`. Not everyone has an `ll` alias.